# Use of django middleware

Tags: python, django

What is django middleware and why we are using the middleware in django.

I want to know, how to use django middleware, and what they are used for? And what things I can't do without them.

Answer (score 1):

Middleware is a framework of hooks into Django’s request/response processing. It’s a light, low-level “plugin” system for globally altering Django’s input or output.

[Creating a custom middleware example](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/18/how-to-create-a-custom-django-middleware.html).